# Metric space results

Tags: general-topology

I came across this question in my topology textbook and I am curious to know the following results in order to use them in my further assignments.

Prove or disprove each of the following statements :

(a) It is possible to define a metric on any non-empty set with at least
two elements

(b) Let X be a metrizable space with metric function dX. The limit of
a convergent sequence in (X, τdX
) is unique.

(c) Every discrete space is metrizable.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: In fact it is possible to define a metric on any non-empty set: it need not have at least two elements. Just set $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$ and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$. You do have to prove that this is a metric, of course.

Answer (score 2):

a) (I assume the set here is endowed with a topology) is not true since a metric space is Hausdorff.

b) is true since a metric space is Hausdorff. If $(x_n)$ has limit $x$ and $y$, there exists $U, V$ open subsets, $U\cap V$ is empty, $x\in U,y\in V$ $N>0$ with $n>N$ implies that $x_n\in U, x_n\in V$ this implies that $x_n\in U\cap V=\phi$ contradiction.

c) is true with $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ and $d(x,x)=0$.

Comment: Your assumption for (a) is incorrect: there is no topology on the set. It’s just a set — as the statement says. The statement is therefore true as in (c).

Answer (score 0):

For any set $X$, for any $p,q\in X$, let $d(p,q)=1$ if $p\ne q$ and $d(p,q)=0$ if $p=q.$ This does not assume that $X$ has any members, or more than one. This is called the discrete metric. Because for any $p\in X,$ the set $\{p\}=B_d(p,1/2)=\{q\in X: d(p,q)<1/2\}$ is open, so every subset of $X$ is open with this metric.